# how to create recursively nested alists from list of strings in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I stayed up all night writing this function that takes a list of strings and turns it into a recursively nested set of alists. I tried using pushnew so that existing strings would not be duplicated but had to create my own test for repetition because I could not get pushnew to do it.

Obviously there is a way to use recursion but I couldn't get that to work because I could not get the destination part of pushnew to call right.

I finally did it a stupid way, but what is the smart way?

```
    (defvar vocab '())

(defun place-down ( a b &optional c d e f g)
    (unless (assoc a vocab :test #'equal)
        (pushnew (cons a '()) vocab :test #'equal))
    (unless (assoc b (cdr(assoc a vocab :test #'equal)):test #'equal)
        (pushnew (cons b '()) (cdr(assoc a vocab :test #'equal :test #'equal))))
    (when c
        (unless (assoc c (cdr(assoc b (cdr(assoc a vocab :test #'equal :test #'equal
            )):test #'equal)):test #'equal)
            (pushnew (cons c '()) (cdr(assoc b (cdr(assoc a vocab :test #'equal
             :test #'equal)):test #'equal)))))
    (when d
        (unless (assoc d (cdr(assoc c (cdr(assoc b (cdr(assoc a vocab :test #'equal 
            :test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)
            (pushnew (cons d '()) (cdr(assoc c (cdr(assoc b (cdr(assoc a vocab :test 
                #'equal :test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)))))
    (when e
        (unless (assoc e (cdr(assoc d (cdr(assoc c (cdr(assoc b (cdr(assoc a vocab 
            :test #'equal :test #'equal)) :test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)
            (pushnew (cons e '()) (cdr(assoc d (cdr(assoc c(cdr(assoc b (cdr(assoc a vocab 
                :test #'equal :test #'equal)) :test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)))))
    (when f
        (unless (assoc f (cdr(assoc e (cdr(assoc d(cdr(assoc c(cdr(assoc b (cdr(assoc a vocab 
            :test #'equal :test #'equal)) :test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal))
        :test #'equal)
            (pushnew (cons f '()) (cdr(assoc e (cdr(assoc d(cdr(assoc c(cdr(assoc b (cdr(assoc a vocab 
                :test #'equal :test #'equal)) :test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)))))
    (when g
        (unless (assoc g (cdr(assoc f (cdr(assoc e(cdr(assoc d(cdr(assoc c(cdr(assoc b (cdr(assoc a vocab
         :test #'equal :test #'equal)) :test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal))
        :test #'equal)):test #'equal)
            (pushnew (cons g '()) (cdr(assoc f (cdr(assoc e(cdr(assoc d(cdr(assoc c(cdr(assoc b (cdr(assoc a vocab 
                :test #'equal :test #'equal)) :test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal)):test #'equal))))))
```

In the reple I  put:

```
*(place-down "this" "is" "it" "the" "life" "we" "live")

* vocab

=> (("this" ("is" ("it" ("the" ("life" ("we" ("live"))))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

The example looks like something [`REDUCE`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm) can solve.

```
(defun place-down (&rest strings)
  (reduce (lambda (string accumulator)
            (if accumulator
                (list string accumulator)
                (list string)))
          strings
          :initial-value nil
          :from-end t))
```

`REDUCE` with an explicit `:initial-value` argument is the case where the given reducing function is called in the most uniform way; otherwise, that function can be called with zero or two arguments, and can even not be called at all if the list has a single element (thank you @jkiiski). If the accumulator is NIL, we discard it. Tests:

```
(place-down "this" "is" "it" "the" "life" "we" "live")
=> ("this" ("is" ("it" ("the" ("life" ("we" ("live")))))))

(place-down "this" "is" "it")
=> ("this" ("is" ("it")))

(place-down "this")
=> ("this")

(place-down)
=> NIL
```

The `:from-end t` arguments makes the operation right-associative.

Comment: You forgot the other special case of `REDUCE`; when called on an input with only one element it returns the element as is. In this case I assume the lone element should still be wrapped in a list.

Comment: Thank you I will study this reduce. I find Lisp to be exciting powerful and uniquely unfathomable. Thank you

Comment: @jkiiski Thanks a lot for catching that

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER 8 > (loop with result = nil
                  for l in (reverse '("this" "is" "it" "the" "life" "we" "live"))
                  do (setf result (list (cons l result)))
                  finally (return result))
(("this" ("is" ("it" ("the" ("life" ("we" ("live"))))))))
```

or

```
CL-USER 9 > (let ((result nil)
                  (list '("this" "is" "it" "the" "life" "we" "live")))
              (dolist (l (reverse list) result)
                (setf result (list (cons l result)))))
(("this" ("is" ("it" ("the" ("life" ("we" ("live"))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you but I did a very poor job of asking the right question. Suppose I already had a tree of nested information and I wanted a function to add to it. It could take ("this" "is" "it" "the" "life" "we" "live") and check if "this" was there or not, adding it if necessary. Perhaps     ("this" ("is" ("it"))) already existed in the tree. "this" being the top level. The function follows it down and adds the ("life" ("we" ("live"))) in the right place without duplicating the first three words.

Comment: @GreggArthurEvans: you can still use a loop or a recursive call to traverse the existing tree. There is no need for the code duplication in your example.

Comment: Thank you, What is called in lisp when we can evaluate to a location or pass a location as opposed to a copy? I am trying to figure out the rules for that because that is where I am having trouble with this function.

Comment: Holy mackerel !!! Mr. Joswig. I figured it out by messing with your example. Thank you so much!